# Grails test-app error

Tags: unit-testing, grails

I am getting below error, when I am using the Domain-expectation plugin and running the Grails Domain Test case.

I could write only one test-case, if I add more than one test case, it is giving the error.

```
|Loading Grails 2.4.3
|Configuring classpath
.
|Environment set to test
.....................................
|Running without daemon...
..............................................
|Compiling 1 source files
.
|Running 2 unit tests... 1 of 2
|Running 2 unit tests... 2 of 2
Failure:  |
testEventNameConstarints(com.dct.santosh.UserSpec)
 |
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Current TestRuntime instance is closed.
    at grails.test.mixin.support.TestMixinRuntimeSupport.getRuntime(TestMixinRuntimeSupport.java:61)
    at grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin.getGrailsApplication(GrailsUnitTestMixin.groovy:149)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1844)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1140)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3690)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1152)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyObjectSupport.getProperty(GroovyObjectSupport.java:36)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoGetPropertySite.getProperty(PogoGetPropertySite.java:47)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGroovyObjectGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:231)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.initialMockDomainSetup(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:123)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:80)
    at com.dct.santosh.UserSpec.mockDomains(UserSpec.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:166)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:56)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at com.dct.santosh.UserSpec.setUp(UserSpec.groovy)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:139)
    at com.lonecyprus.grails.test.Specification.runBare(Specification.groovy)
    at com.lonecyprus.grails.test.ConstraintSpecification.runBare(ConstraintSpecification.groovy)
    at com.dct.santosh.UserSpec.runBare(UserSpec.groovy)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:122)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:142)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:125)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:129)
    at com.lonecyprus.grails.test.Specification.run(Specification.groovy)
    at com.lonecyprus.grails.test.ConstraintSpecification.run(ConstraintSpecification.groovy)
    at com.dct.santosh.UserSpec.run(UserSpec.groovy)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.runTest(TestSuite.java:255)
    at junit.framework.TestSuite.run(TestSuite.java:250)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.JUnit38ClassRunner.run(JUnit38ClassRunner.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:127)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:138)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore$run$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.spock.GrailsSpecTestType.doRun(GrailsSpecTestType.groovy:147)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.support.GrailsTestTypeSupport.run(GrailsTestTypeSupport.groovy:121)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:415)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.processTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:395)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1152)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaClassSite.java:66)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:49)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$_runAllTests_closure7.doCall(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:313)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1270)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:324)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1207)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1016)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:423)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.callClosureForMapEntry(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:4271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.DefaultGroovyMethods.each(DefaultGroovyMethods.java:1408)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.dgm$151.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite$PojoMetaMethodSiteNoUnwrapNoCoerce.invoke(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:271)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaMethodSite.call(PojoMetaMethodSite.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:299)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy:214)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner.runAllTests(GrailsProjectTestRunner.groovy)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.test.runner.GrailsProjectTestRunner$runAllTests$0.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.runInstance(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:128)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.run(ForkedGrailsProjectClassExecutor.groovy:74)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.fork.testing.ForkedGrailsTestRunner.main(ForkedGrailsTestRunner.groovy:75)
|Completed 2 unit tests, 1 failed in 0m 9s
.................Tests FAILED 
|
 - view reports in C:\Hersheys_Workspace\TestDeePlugin\target\test-reports
Error |
Forked Grails VM exited with error
```

My Domain test case class is here

```
package com.dct.santosh

import com.lonecyprus.grails.test.*
import grails.test.mixin.Mock

@Mock(User)
class UserSpec extends ConstraintSpecification {

    def setup() {
        Expectations.applyTo User
    }

    def cleanup() {
    }

    void testShouldDoNothing() {
        Expectations.applyTo User

        def user = new User()
        //user.expectNameIsNotBlank()
        //user.expectNameIsNotNullable()

        user."password is not blank"
        user."password is not nullable"
        user."name is not blank"
        user."name is not nullable"
    }

    void testEventNameConstarints() {
        Expectations.applyTo User

        def user = new User()
        //user.expectNameIsNotBlank()
        //user.expectNameIsNotNullable()

        user."name is not blank"
        user."name is not nullable"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hurrah!!!

I got the solution by myself. And the answer is instead of @Mock(User) write @TestFor(User).

This solves the problem.